# How to convert the values of an attribute having categorical values to integer type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataset in which one of its columns is `Ex-Showroom_Price`, and I'm trying to convert its values to integers but I'm getting an error.

```
import pandas as pd

#reading the dataset
cars = pd.read_csv('cars_engage_2022.csv')

cars["Ex-Showroom_Price"]  = int(cars["Ex-Showroom_Price"] .split()[-1].replace(',',''))
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-d65bfedf76a4> in <module>
----> 1 cars["Ex-Showroom_Price"]  = int(cars["Ex-Showroom_Price"] .split()[-1].replace(',',''))

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Values of `Ex-Showroom_Price`:

```
Rs. 2,92,667
Rs. 2,36,447
Rs. 2,96,661
Rs. 3,34,768
Rs. 2,72,223
:
```

Comment: @LancelotduLac
Please check this one

Comment: What is `cars`? Python does not have a built-in type called "dataset". Please provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: `.split()` On what character are you trying to split?

Comment: @YScharf split() with no arguments splits on whitespace

Comment: This problem arises because *cars* is an *int*. You were probably expecting it be a *dict*

Comment: @martineau
 It's a dataframe.

Comment: It appears that not all of the values in the `Ex-Showroom_Price` column are strings (and at least one is an `int`).

Answer (score 0):

First split `string` into list.

`df["cars-list"] = df['Ex-Showroom_Price'].str.split()`

Then remove commas (',').

`df["cars-int"] = df["cars-list"].apply(lambda x: x[-1].replace(',','')  )`

Then convert into `int`.

`df["cars-int"] = df["cars-int"].astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `str` methods over an array of data. Assuming your `cars` is a `DataFrame`, you could try with methods iterating over single cells. `str` comes in handy for `DataFrame`s

```
data = ["Rs. 2,92,667", "Rs. 2,36,447", "Rs. 2,96,661", "Rs. 3,34,768", "Rs. 2,72,223"]
cars = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Ex-Showroom_Price'])

cars["Ex-Showroom_Price"] = cars["Ex-Showroom_Price"].str.replace(r'.* ([\d,]+)+$', r'\1').str.replace(',', '').astype('int32')
```

I've used a regular expression here and I've kept your `','` substitution for simplicity, but you may merge them in one.

**Note:** the above code runs well, but as @martineau pointed out, the error you are getting seems to be related to the format of your data. Please, ensure `data` conforms with the format I'm assuming here, or expand you question with further details.